# DEADLOCK_WRAP error when using Berkeley Db in python (bsddb)

Tags: python, berkeley-db, bsddb

I am using a berkdb to store a huge list of key-value pairs but for some reason when i try to access some of the data later i get this error:

```
try:
    key = 'scrape011201-590652'
    contenttext = contentdict[key]
except:
    print the error


<type 'exceptions.KeyError'> 'scrape011201-590652' in 
contenttext = contentdict[key]\n', '  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/bsddb/__init__.py",
line 223, in __getitem__\n    return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  #   
self.db[key]\n', 'File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 62, in 
DeadlockWrap\n    return function(*_args, **_kwargs)\n', '  File 
"/usr/lib64/python2.5/bsddb/__init__.py", line 223, in <lambda>\n    return 
_DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]\n']
```

I am not sure what DeadlockWrap is but there isnt any other program or process accessing the berkdb or writing to it (as far as i know,) so not sure how we could get a deadlock, if its referring to that. Is it possible that I am trying to access the data to rapidly? I have this function call in a loop, so something like

```
for i in hugelist:
    #try to get a value from the berkdb
    #do something with it
```

I am running this with multiple datasets and this error only occurs with one of them, the largest one, not the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the `DeadlockWrap` stuff is not relevant here. It's simply a way to [automagically provide retries with a back-off strategy](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/bsddb.dbutils-module.html#DeadlockWrap). In other words, if the database manipulation fails, it waits a little bit then tries again, a number of times before finally failing.

You seem to be getting a `KeyError` from your dictionary `get` operation which is more likely to be due  to the fact that the key you're using doesn't actually exist in the database.

Try your code with something like:

```
try:
    key = 'scrape011201-590652'
    if not contentdict.has_key(key):
        print "Urk!, No record for %s"%(key)
    contenttext = contentdict[key]
except:
    print the error
```

This should show you if the record doesn't exist in the table (by outputting the `Urk!` message). As to what you do in that case, it depends on your architecture. You would probably want to return either `None` or an empty string. You may also want to do exactly what you're doing now (raising an exception).

Answer (score 0):

```
contenttext = contentdict[key] if contentdict.has_key(key) else None
```